# copy columns of a csv file into postgresql table

Tags: postgresql

I have a CSV file with 12 - 11 - 10 or 5 columns.

After creating a PostgreSQL table with 12 columns, I want to copy this CSV into the table.

I use this request:

```
COPY absence(champ1, champ2, num_agent, nom_prenom_agent, code_gestion, code_service, calendrier_agent, date_absence, code_absence, heure_absence, minute_absence, periode_absence)
FROM 'C:\temp\absence\absence.csv' 
DELIMITER '\' 
CSV
```

My CSV file contains 80000 line.

Ex :

```
20\05\  191\MARKEY CLAUDIE\GA0\51110\39H00\21/02/2020\1471\03\54\Matin
21\05\  191\MARKEY CLAUDIE\GA0\51110\39H00\\8130\7H48\Formation avec repas\
30\05\  191\MARKEY CLAUDIE\GA0\51430\39H00\\167H42\
22\9993\Temps de déplacement\98\37
```

when I execute the request, I get a message indicating that there is missing data for the lines with less than 12 fields.

Is there a trick?

Comment: The only way is to set default value for columns, which are missing. Postgresql will handle it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`copy` is extremely fast and efficient, but less flexible because of that. Specifically it can't cope with files that have a different number of "columns" for each line.

You can either use a different import tool, or if you want to stick to built-in tools, copy the file into staging table that only has a single column, then use Postgres string functions to split the lines into the columns:

```
create unlogged table absence_import
(
  line text
);

\COPY absence_import(line) FROM 'C:\temp\absence\absence.csv' DELIMITER E'\b' CSV
```

`E'\b'` is the "backspace" character which can't really appear in a text file, so no column splitting is taking place.

Once you have imported the file, you can split the line using `string_to_array()` and the insert that into the real table:

```
insert into absence(champ1, champ2, num_agent, nom_prenom_agent, code_gestion, code_service, calendrier_agent, date_absence, code_absence, heure_absence, minute_absence, periode_absence)
select line[1], line[2], line[3], .....
from (
  select string_to_array(line, '\') as line
  from absence_import
) t;
```

If there are non-text columns, might need to cast the values to the target data type explicitly: e.g. `line[3]::int`.

You can add additional expressions to deal with missing columns, e.g. something like: `coalesce(line[10], 'default value')`

Comment: I find this : https://www.jesuisundev.com/massive-import-via-symfony2-command-depuis-fichier-csv/

And it's works fine...80000 in 2 minutes

Ijust add this :
$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

And flush (synfony/doctrine) by 20 line.

Thanks all

Comment: @jimwest: that's what I meant with "You can either use a different import tool"